# When to start deleting video elements to prevent browser lag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website which will keep on adding video players to the page as the page is being scrolled down. Though I have some concerns that large amount of video players on a page can cause lag on the website and cause the website to slow down. I think I have experienced slow down during some tests of my website. So is it possible to detect whether the website is being slowed down due of the amount of elements on the web and so I can start deleting the video elements from the top of the page?

`index.html:`

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    timeout = undefined;

for (var x=0;x<50;x++) {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
    video.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    video.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
    video.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_3840x2160_60fps_18000k.mp4";
    video.controls = true;
    content.appendChild(video);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var $this = this;
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var content_margin_top = $this.innerHeight * 0.11;
        var last_player = content.children[content.querySelectorAll("video").length - 1]; 
        if (last_player.offsetTop - content_margin_top <= $this.scrollY) {
            for (var x=0;x<10;x++) {
                var video = document.createElement("video");
                video.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
                video.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
                video.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_3840x2160_60fps_18000k.mp4";
                video.controls = true;
                content.appendChild(video);
            }
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(108, 171, 247);
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 98%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    left: 1%;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd just open the inspector (ctrl + shift + I) and check the performance on your machine. Preferably do an Audit in there for your site to see if it performs bad. And at what time should you get rid of em? I'd say roughly when they're scrolled beyond one or two rows of players, and load them one or two rows beyond when they become visible. Also look into different ways of playing up a video, e.g. it might be better to stream it to a `<canvas>` element than to a `<video>` element.

Comment: Do websites like `instagram` and `facebook` remove `video` as the page is being scrolled? As in I think that they keep on adding `video` to the page and it doesn't lag at all.

Comment: Good question. Open the inspector, visit those sites and look at the DOM while you scroll.

Comment: @SimonHyll From my knowledge, I couldn't see anything relevant.

Comment: You can use setTimeout like this:

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#divID').remove();
}, 5000);

The 5000 (ms) means 5 seconds. You should replace divID with your own div/element id.

You can make sure that the div exists first using length:

setTimeout(function(){
  if ($('#divID').length > 0) {
    $('#divID').remove();
  }
}, 5000) meaning you can remove the old content and replace with new content afer some timespan.

Comment: 50 videos tags is ridiculous. You can run 50 videos from 1 video tag like Youtube does. A video is meant to be viewed one at a time. If it's a question of presentation, use thumbnails like Youtube.

Comment: if monitor the performance of the website is too complicated you can simply remove the previous element that is off the viewport. basically is a two-direction lazyloading. then you can see you always has maximum 10 video element on your page, the rest of them will be append or remove dynamically base on user's scroll direction. There are also many 3rd party lib can do that.

Comment: You might want to rely on the IntersectionObserver API: once a `<video>` element has been scrolled out of view, you replace the element with a thumbnail of the video instead.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm trying to make something like `Instagram`, `Facebook` or `9GAG`. And I'm assuming that their web pages consist 50+ `video` at the same time but playing the visible `video` only

Comment: @Terry as I scroll down the page I assign the `video` with the poster only and remove it src

Comment: @jilykate can you reference me to the 3rd party lib

Comment: @Aman *"...web pages consist 50+ video at the same time **but playing the visible video only**"* That observation should lead you to the same conclusion as mine: ***One video tag and many thumbnails.*** Although I've never checked (and I'm not going to because  I'm sure someone will chime in if I'm wrong), but I'm sure there's 50+ thumbnail links and one video tag. I cannot fathom any circumstance that could justify or the need for the use of 50 video tags on a webpage. You should reassess your approach.

Comment: @Aman, for example http://airbnb.io/infinity/#reference, it is from airbnb, here is a demo https://airbnb.io/infinity/demo-on.html. In the demo, no matter how far you scroll, the max item will be around 70 always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would think about the issue in a slightly different way: What should I do to make that page work as fast as possible, downloading as little data as possible and render only necessary containers when needed?

My recommendations:

1) Don't append and init video containers on during scroll. Render only thumbnails for future video containers using `img` tags. Making lazy loading for these images should be considered as well. Add "play" button to the center of preview container. Once user clicks on the button - render `video` tag with a proper src and play it.

2) Don't use a scroll event listener to detect containers offsets and lazy loading. Use [Intersection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead.

Comment: 1) In my original project, I append `video` tags in the page and assign them with a `poster` (thumbnails). If any `video` is seen to be in the middle of screen, it gets assigned to `src`.

2) I'll see if Intersection API is any good